# Can someone shed some light on how the effect in this bar photo was done?

Tags: post-processing, reverse-engineering, effect

I am very intrigued by this photo. Can anyone shed some light into how this effect could be achieved?

[image: Night Photo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that it's saturated a little bit, contrast increased and split tone was applied towards blue. Here's an example how you can split the tone using Lightroom 4.

In the first example, the Hue was 237 (blues) and Saturation value was 29

[image]

While in the second example, the Hue was also 237 and Saturation value was 100. As you can see this image is more blueish than the first one

[image]

Comment: from what i can gather on the internets, split toning convers an image into sepia like dual tone photo.. all colors are lost due to b&w conversion

Comment: not necessarily, split toning allows you to give the highlight parts of the image a specific tone and the shadow parts a specific tone, and you can control how much the tone will affect the hightlight/shadows by increase or decrease the saturation, please see my updated answer

Comment: you can split tone a colour image and use opacity to lower the effect